# Avoid file uploading in Dropzone.js - interested in JSON contents in browser

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js to allow a user to upload some .json files to a web app. These json files are then parsed and used on a different page.

I've got this working using the 'addedfile' event and a FileReader() object.

However, I would like to avoid dropzone trying to upload the files and making a failed POST call to '/undefined'.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `autoProcessQueue` dropzone option to `false`. With `autoProcessQueue` set to `false` dropzone will not upload files independently. Check [Dropzone.js documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-autoProcessQueue) for more details.

Comment: I found out about autoProcessQueue, however, I need to Process the files because I can only go to the next page of my Angular app if all files have been read and processed. This requires the 'queuecomplete' event to fire.. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Dropzone call `queuecomplete` callback only when it uploads all files. If you don't want dropzone to upload files, then it will never call `queuecomplete`. You can use either `addedfile` callback or `files` dropzone property to process JSON files. Use your own `complete` callback within JSON processing logic to navigate to another page.